# SD/MMC CID Card ID available to PC programmer thru USB Card Reader?

Tags: c#, sd-card, serial-number

I want to get the product serial number of SD card for security purpose.......
I google a lot after i got this [link](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/31/GettingAnSDCardSerialNumberInTheCompactFramework.aspx).
But in this link i can't get ManufacturerID and Serial Number i am vary confused.
If you have any solution than suggest me. 
And i also got this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173.aspx)
But this give me only Drive volume number this will change after every format.

And i also Got the serial number in android mobile application but I want serial number in C# desktop appplication.....

If any one know how to get Unique serial number of SD card than please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use WMI query for finding the serial number

first find the PNP id then use following WMI query

```
 SELECT SerialNumber FROM win32_diskdrive where  pnpdeviceid ='SDcard pnp id'
```